# Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new' wrapped in withRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two React class components:

**Class A**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export class A extends React.Component {

}

export default withRouter(A);
```

**Class B**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import A from './A';

export class B extends A {

}

export default withRouter(B);
```

When i render class B, i get 'Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'' error. When i remove in **Class A**(parent of Class B) `withRouter` wrapper - all becomes fine. Why does this happen and what should i do to use exact this structure? Babel version/config? Router version? Anything else? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inherit from the original component class A and not the wrapped version! For this you can use the static [`WrappedComponent` property](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter/componentwrappedcomponent):

```js
export class B extends A.WrappedComponent {

}
```

Or, since you already export `A` separately as named export, you could import the original unwrapped class instead of the wrapped one (this is *instead* of the above solution):

```js
import { A } from './A';
```

Comment: So are you sure that none of babel plugins or configs have no influence on it?

Comment: I'm not sure but it struck me as odd that you tried inserting the router twice this way.

Comment: Better change to `import { A } from './A';`

Comment: @Bergi Good idea. I didn't notice `A` was exported separately already.